# jQuery animate: How to avoid elements being displaced?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Here is a small example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FXFUB/)

```
var elemOrigPos;    

$('div.box').hover(
function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    elemOrigPos =  $this.position();
    var offset = 50;

    $this.stop(true, true).animate({
        'width': '200px',
        'height': '200px',
        'top': (elemOrigPos.top - offset) + 'px',
        'left': (elemOrigPos.left - offset) + 'px'
    }, 150);
},
function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        'width': '100px',
        'height': '100px',
        'top': (elemOrigPos.top) + 'px',
        'left': (elemOrigPos.left) + 'px'
    }, 150);
}
);
```

It works fine if you hover slowly over the elements but as soon as you hover more quickly over them, they lose their original position. I guess it has something to do with that I use position() before the animation completes but wasn't able to figure out a solution for it.

Thanks in advance for any tips or hints to fix this behaviour. :)

Comment: When you hover quickly over the squares the elemOrigPos gets replaced by the next square's position before it has a change to finish the animation.

Comment: Yes I know. I just wasn't able to come up with an elegant solution like @Tigraine did. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your code and the main problem is that you are always resetting origPosition to the current position of the element when you hover (and it may not be the right one since it could be mid-animation).
The solution to this is rather simple, just save the original position independent from the actual position.

What I did was simply save the original position in the jQuery.data() so that all calculations can be done from that rather than the actual position where it may or may not be right now.

```
$('div.box')
        .each(function() {
            $(this).data('position', $(this).position());
        })
        .hover(
        function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            elemOrigPos =  $(this).data('position');
            var offset = 50;
    ....
```

Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FXFUB/1/

Comment: Wow, thats amazing and thanks for teaching me something new by using jQuery.data() in that way. I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm able to do it. :) Awesome!